# python: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, string, input, floating-point

im submitting this code..

```
a = float(input())
b = float(input())
c = float(input())

if abs(b - c) < a < (b + c) and abs(a - c) < b < (a + c) and abs(a - b) < c < (a + b):
    print("Perimetro = " + str(a + b + c))
else:
    print("Area = " + str(((a + b) * c) / 2))
```

and for me it was correct, but, as a response, i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 1, in <module>
    a = float(input())
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '6.0 4.0 2.0'
Command exited with non-zero status (1)
```

which i dont get it cause i converted the strings in the begginning.

what am i doing wrong here?

thanks x

Comment: Can a number have multiple decimal points like you have here: `6.0 4.0 2.0`. You need to split the string and process them individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are entering all the three values at once. Add one value and then press enter. For example:

```
>>> a = float(input())
6.0
>>> b = float(input())
4.0
>>> c = float(input())
2.0
>>> a, b, c
(6.0, 4.0, 2.0)
```

OR, get the single string and `split` the string to assign the value to `a`, `b` and `c`. For example:

```
>>> a, b, c = [float(item) for item in input().split()]
6.0 4.0 2.0
>>> a, b, c
(6.0, 4.0, 2.0)
```